# UUID for BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I need something like a UUID for BigQuery tables. I found dataset.id which gives me a unique identifier for a dataset but not the case for a table.

I can't seem to find documentation on it. Is it possible to get UUID for a table in a dataset in BigQuery? Searching API docs surfaced nothing.

Comment: If you're looking for unique identifier (and not necessarily [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), we know table name is unique per dataset so `project_id.dataset.table` will always be unique as well.  " I found dataset.id...." are you referring to "Dataset ID" (which is just `project.dataset`) shown on BQ UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Google Cloud resources, including BigQuery tables, have a [full resource name](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names#full_resource_name) that uniquely identifies said resource.

For BigQuery tables, the full resource name is `//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATA_SET/tables/TABLE`

You can use the full resource name to uniquely identify a BigQuery table instead of relying on a surrogate UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Table names are unique per dataset, If you have to use an ID you may use view ID e.g. projectID.datasetName.tableName you can also see this at the details tab of the table in the console.

Additionally you can query table details by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA, Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#get_table_information_using_information_schema

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you ask, since project.dataset.table uniquely identifies a table thats no a problem.

However if you want a random uuid for rows, the following SQL will give a random uuid that you can plug in a row field:

SELECT GENERATE_UUID() AS uuid;

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/uuid_functions?hl=es-419

regards